# Name for a public const and private writable attribute?

Tags: c++

Programming in C++, I often want to give the user of a class read-only access to an attribute, and the class itself read-write access. I hate `XxxGet()` methods, so I often use a `public const &` to a private attribute, like this:

```
class counter {
  private:
     int _count;

  public:
     const int & count;

     counter : _count( 0 ), count( _count ){}

     void inc( void ){ _counter++; }
};
```

Is there a common name for this trick?

Comment: Accessors (getters/setters) are not only means to restrict access to some member variables, they also hide the implementation. Your "trick" leaks the implementation, meaning that you will never be able to change the way `count` is represented in your class. What if you decide some day that `count` would be better computed on-the-fly, or that accessing the count should be synchronized to accomodate multi-threading? You would have to modify all the users of `counter`. You should probably stick to well-accepted idioms, and use getters.

Comment: @Seb: probably not, this comes with more pain than glory (i.e. it is prone to create bugs in the application while it adds little to no value over a plain accessor)

Comment: @Wouter:  I wonder why you "hate" `XxxGet()` methods?  I mean, I hate them too but I'd use them here, because that is exactly what you need.

Comment: @JD: Dunno, I guess it feels wrong for me. I don't like the () for something that (at the very least conceptually) dows nothing but yielding a value. Like havling two write pi() every time I need that constant.

Comment: @Wouter: They are not really the same... pi is a universal constant, while there are many accessors that represent an operation on the type, like `std::vector<>::size()` (read as *get_size*), which is a great example of why accessors can be better than public fields/references: the implementations of `vector` in g++ and Dinkumware STL don't have a `size` field, `size()` is calculated in terms of other implementation details (difference between stored pointers)

Comment: @Wouter:  Do you feel like your wasting cycles on an unnecesarry function call?  It can be inlined, removing that.  Do you feel like you're wasting keystrokes?  Look at it this way, your getting the benefit of IntelliSense (et al) telling the user that they are getting a `const` reference back.  Don't let your code suffer bad design simply because something "feels wrong" if you can't identify what's wrong about it.

Comment: **Just now** I thought of a name that could be considered the same pattern. Though not typically used for member variables.

Comment: @JD: No, I don't care about wasting a few cycles, otherwise I would not use this trick in the first place! I mainly program microcontrollers, so I do care a little about RAM use - which I know is an argument against my trick.

Comment: @Wouter An aside: in FP you can think about constants as nullary functions. So, calling them makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the fact that a method is called, I just hate the () after the name, it gets in my way when reading. But maybe I'll just have to swallow my pride on this aspect.

Answer (score 24):

My personal name for that trick would be *bad idea*.

I would avoid the approach that you are following, as it incurs extra unneeded cost. If you add accessors they can be inlined as needed, with the only penalty of having to type an extra pair of parentheses:

```
class counter {
    int _count;
public:
    counter() : _count() {}
    int count() const { return _count; }
    void inc() { ++_count; }
};
```

The main difference is that in your solution you are incrementing the size of the object by one reference (for most implementations this means pointer), and then each access requires an extra indirection. On the other hand, with the accessor, the actual variable is used, the function will be optimized away (inlined, and resolved to a single read to the variable).

As of a proper name for that type of construct, well, I have never seen your particular construct in C++, but if you consider other languages, that is the basic concept of a *property* in C#, where you can make the getter public and the setter private.

**EDIT**: I guess that *bad idea* can be misinterpreted as just a personal opinion (which it is), but consider the side effects of that design:

Because of the reference in the object, you inhibit the implicit definition of the *assignment operator*. Much worse, the *copy constructor* will *compile* but not work as expected:

```
// consider the implementation with the const reference
counter c1;
counter c2( c1 );          // compiles, so it must work
c2.inc();
std::cout << c2.count;   // outputs 0
// c2 = c1;              // error: well, at least this does not compile!
```

The problem is that the compiler generated copy constructor will make the `count` reference in `c2` refer to the same `int` that the `count` reference in `c1` refers to, which might lead to hard-to-find subtle issues in your code that are actually quite hard to debug.

Comment: Thx for precising my point about copy constructor. +2 then :)

Comment: The handcrafted assignment operator would just assign the `_count` member and leave the reference as it is. The copy constructor is a worse problem, though.

Comment: @UncleBens: Right... I got confused with having to reassign the reference but you are right that the reference does not need to be reseated as it will still refer to the local member. I have removed that comment from the answer. The copy constructor is also simple to implement, but it has to be manual and the problem is that it increases the chances for mistakes.

Comment: you never initialized _count.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: sorry? `counter() : _count() {}`?

Comment: Blah, I forgot about default-initalization.  I simply noticed that the OP had `counter : _count( 0 ), count( _count ) {}` and you didn't.

Answer (score 15):

**Edit**

**Just now** I thought of a name that could be considered the same pattern. Though not typically used for member variables.

There could actually be a name for this, as has been made popular by the Boost Tuple library as well as the TR1/C++11 implementations:

### Tieing

Typical example:

```
 tuple<int> tie(ref(some_var));
 // or shorter:
 auto tied = tie(var1, var2, var3);
```

### Assignment complications

The closest name for this (anti?) pattern I could _*immediately* think of before, is: **pointer or reference aliasing**. It is not a very good idea for many reasons, some of which have been mentioned

- class layout + size
- copy/assignment semantics
- compiler optimizations: the compiler will shun from making assumptions about the value of (register-allocated) variables when it *knows* references could point to the same memory location.

In addition to the points David makes, the compiler will be unable to generate default

- *semantically valid* copy constructor
- assignment operator
- move assignment operator

for your class now that contains references. Note also that your class can't possibly be POD anymore

Comment: @David: agreed, I too was hoping for a requirement to use `T(T&&) = default;` to explicitely summon a default move constructor...

Answer (score 1):

A number of others have already condemned this idea, and I (mostly) tend to agree with them. Although quite a few people probably dislike it (at least) as much, if I was going to support something on this order, I'd do something like this:

```
class counter { 
    int count_;
public:
    counter(int init=0) : count_(init) {}
    operator int() const { return count_; }
    void inc() { ++count_; }
};
```

The one problem with this is one that's shared with implicit conversions in general: that the implicit conversion can happen even when you don't want it to. OTOH, the fact that it's a user-supplied conversion actually eliminates many of the problems -- only one implicit conversion will happen automatically in any given situation, so (for example) the fact that you've supplied a conversion to `int` will *not* mean that a `counter` with a value of 0 can be implicitly converted from a `counter` to an `int` to a (null) `pointer to T`, because that would involve two implicit conversions.

There are times this can cause a problem anyway, in which case (as of C++11) you can make the conversion operator `explicit`, so it'll only happen when/if the user does an explicit conversion like:

```
counter t;

int x = t;  // allowed by code above, but not with `explicit` conversion operator.

int y = static_cast<int>(t);    // allowed with `explicit` conversion operator.
```